# Nyaya Vaishnavism

Tags: bhagavad-gita, vaishnavism, nyaya

I wanna be a Nyaya, but follow the Vaishnava school of thought and text like the Bhagavad Gita. Are there any Vaishnava scholars who commented on Nyaya Sutras and Bridged them using Upanishads and Bhagavad Gita?

Comment: You can have closest to nyaya school is - *Advaita* school (if you go by concepts and arguments). Infact Advaita can be established via nyaya school too (read - AdvaitaSiddhi for the arguments). Additionally you can interpret both Bhagavat Gita and Uttara Gita (later is Advaitic) which no Vaishnava sampradayas do. A range of vaishnav texts on tantra, yoga, yoga Vasishtha, etc are rejected by modern Vaishnava sampradayas will be available to you.

Comment: @AbhasKumarSinha that's cool, but Nyaya believes Ishvara an entity wrote the Vedas correct?

Comment: Most serious philosophers of vedAnta would know a very good amount of navya-nyAya. Examples being Sri Madhusudhana Saraswati (advaitin and Krishna bhakta), Sri Vyasaraya (Vaishnava dvaitin) and recently Sri Ramanuja Tatacharya (Sri Vaishnava). Navya-nyAya methods are extensively used in vedAntic debates and discussions.

Comment: @Haridasa directly or indirectly all schools do follow the same, including Advaita Vedanta. But the role of ishvara minimises here a bit (there are reasons). Also the definition of nyaya school and Advaita school ishvara is same. So this shouldn't be a problem either way b

Comment: @observer Ha yes, I have heard about Navya Nyaya, and I think it is an extension to classical nyaya. From what OP's concern is noted. I think once someone gets a direct interpretation of Brahma Sutras via BG, the problem would get solved, because nyaya schools have well documented commentary on Brahma Sutras.

Comment: @User29449 interesting would there be any Nyaya-like rational methodology for Vaishnava schools?

Comment: @observer same for you do you know?

Comment: @Haridasa I don't have any Nyaya Vaishnavism. There could be a few Vaishnavas that could have followed Nyaya. Vaishnavism is predominantly extremist Advaita and not more than Shankaracharya order follows them to some extent imo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, It is not possible to be A Rigorous Naiyayika and Follow A Vedantic text of Vaishnavism such as the Bhagavad Gita. Nyaya is one of the rival schools of vedanta so as a whole, it can never be compatible with a text of Vedanta such as the Bhagavad gita.

Moreover Vaishnava texts categorize Nyaya as one among the Tamasa or heretical doctrines alongside samkhya, charvaka, bauddha,Vaisiseka, Saiva etc.

> शृणु देवि प्रवक्ष्यामि **तामसानि यथाक्रमम्** २। तेषां स्मरणमात्रेण मोहः
> स्याज्ज्ञानिनामपि । प्रथमं हि मयैवोक्तं शैवं पाशुपतादिकम् ३।
> मच्छक्त्यावेशितैर्व्विप्रैः प्रोक्तानि च ततः शृणु । कणादेन तु
> संप्रोक्तं शास्त्रं वैशेषिकं महत् ४। **गौतमेन तथा न्यायं** सांख्यं तु
> कपिलेन वै । धिषणेन तथा प्रोक्तं चार्व्वाकमतिगर्हितम् ५। दैत्यानां
> नाशनार्थाय विष्णुना बुद्धरूपिणा ।
>
> **O goddess, listen. I shall tell you about the vicious texts in a sequence.** **By merely remembering them even the wise ones would be
> deluded**, First I myself proclaimed the Śaiva, Pāśupata (texts) etc.
> Hear about the ones which were proclaimed by the brāhmaṇas into whom
> my power had entered, after that: Kaṇāda proclaimed the great
> Vaiśeṣika text.
>
> **Similarly Gautama (proclaimed the doctrine of) Nyāya**, and Kapila (proclaimed) Sāṃhkhya. Dhiṣaṇa (Bṛhaspati) in the same way
> (proclaimed) the much censured Cārvāka (doctrine); Viṣṇu of the form
> of Buddha proclaimed the false Buddhist doctrine and those of the
> naked and wearing dark blue garmentsfor the destruction of the demons.

***Padma Purana Section 6 - Uttara-Khaṇḍa Chapter 236***

Hence it is not possible to be A Vaishnava and a Naiyayika at the same time.